# Document_New event on launching Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA addin which I want to run every time someone opens a document. It's working fine for opening existing documents (AutoOpen) and creating new documents from the File > New menu (AutoNew) but when I just open Word up for the first time, neither of these events are firing. The only event I can seem to hook into is the AutoExec event and this is not great as the document doesn't exist yet so ActiveWindow is null.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub AutoNew
    MsgBox "New"
End Sub

Sub AutoOpen
    MsgBox "Open"
End Sub

Sub AutoExec
    MsgBox "Exec"
End Sub
```

Comment: See [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/documentevents.htm) - your question doesn't say when/how you are trying those events but it seems they cannot be stored in an Addin.

Comment: You can do this using event handlers. See here for an example in Excel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211482(v=office.14).aspx. Beware, though; Word is not great at triggering events consistently. If you double-click a file rather than opening it from Word, for instance, certain Application events don't fire. For my purposes, this is ok (the actions I want to trigger are not essential) but if you need a guarantee that the events will fire this may not help you. Here's a list of the application events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841714(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So can you help me with which event will fire when I launch Word that will allow me to modify a property on ActiveWindow?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with DocumentOpen and NewDocument. An additional level of complexity exists if you need to support ProtectedView documents; Word triggers a different event. I've found that if I try to check for that event (and it doesn't occur) it raises an error. I didn't had much luck and eventually it wasn't worth the time I was spending. I've posted an example below of some code that opens the Style Pane when a document is opened or a new one created (assuming the add-in is loading) and expands the style margin in draft view if not already expanded.

In my UI module:

```
Dim X As New clsAppEvent 'This is in the declarations

Public Sub OnRibbonLoad(objRibbon As IRibbonUI)
    Do While Documents.Count = 0
      DoEvents
    Loop ' I find this useful as sometimes it seems my ribbon loads before the document. 
    Call Register_Event_Handler
    ' Other stuff
End Sub

Private Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Then, in a class module I call clsAppEvent:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentOpen(ByVal Doc As Document)
    App.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewDocument(ByVal Doc As Document)
    App.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub App_WindowActivate(ByVal Doc As Document, ByVal Wn As Window)
    If Wn.StyleAreaWidth <= 0 Then
      Wn.StyleAreaWidth = 60
    End If
End Sub
```

Other than the caveats I've noted above, the one problem I've had is if a user has Auto code in their Normal template as well. This has only come up once so I haven't investigated it.

I wish I could find the site where I learned about this (and from which the Register_Event_Handler was derived. If I find it I'll add a comment.

Comment: Oh, obviously I'm using Word with the ribbon (2010 in my case). I should have asked what version you wanted this for....